# Can't install acroread - 'dpkg returned an error code (1)'

Tags: installation, adobe-acrobat

After running `sudo apt-get install acroread`, I got the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libldap2 libgnome-speech7
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acroread
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/60.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 142 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 237901 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking acroread (from .../acroread_9.5.1-1precise1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread_9.5.1-1precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./opt/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/intellinux/nppdf.so': No space left on device
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
/usr/bin/mandb: can't write to /var/cache/man/1645: No space left on device
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread_9.5.1-1precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you have sufficient space in your device or partition. Check that with `df -h` command

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are out of space, to check your hdd just run:

```
df -h
```

If this command tells you that the **use%** is at like 99% or something around that, clean it using this command:

```
apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean
```

You may also try to remove unneeded packages from your system using this command:

```
deborphan | xargs aptitude --purge remove
```

After you have run these commands, try to install `acroread` again and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The important line is:

```
/usr/bin/mandb: can't write to /var/cache/man/1645: No space left on device
```

The partition where the directory `/var` lives has no more space left. You can try to delete some unnecessary files. Sometimes the directory `/var/cache/apt/archives` contains lots of unneeded package files. Please check if you could remove some files in `/var` and retry.